# Spring MVC Controller testing, and mocking many classes

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, mockito

We have many Controllers in our system, and many Spring Data repositories.

I would like to write tests for my controllers that run through my MVC context.

However, it seems pretty cumbersome, and just not right, to have to, by hand, mock every service and repository in my system, so that I can test the controllers

e.g.

FooControllerTest.java

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextHierarchy(value = {
    @ContextConfiguration(classes = { MockServices.class }),
    @ContextConfiguration({ "classpath:/META-INF/spring/mvc-servlet-context.xml" }),
})
public class FooControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Autowired
    private FooRepository fooRepository;

    @Autowired
    private FooService fooService; 

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        mvc = webAppContextSetup(wac).build();
    }

    @Test
    public final void list() {
        when(fooRepository.findAll()).thenReturn(...);
        mvc.perform(get("/foo"))...
    }

    @Test
    public final void create() {
        Foo fixture = ...
        when(fooService.create(fixture)).thenReturn(...);
        mvc.perform(post("/foo"))...
    }

}
```

MockServices.java

```
@Configuration
public class MockServices {

    @Bean
    public FooRespository fooRepositiory() {
        return Mockito.mock(FooRespository.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public FooService fooService() {
        return Mockito.mock(FooService.class);
    }

    //even though we are "only" testing FooController, we still need to mock BarController's dependencies, because BarController is loaded by the web app context.
    @Bean
    public BarService barService() {
        return Mockito.mock(FooService.class);
    }

    //many more "mocks"

}
```

I do not really want to use `standaloneSetup()` (want to use the production configuration, eg conversion services, error handlers, etc)

is this just the price I have to pay for writing controller tests so far down the line?

Seems there should be something like `mock every class annotated with @Service` or  `mock every interface that extends JpaRepository`

Comment: In the controller test, could you simply do **@Mock YourService service** and set that on your controller and expect/verify your mocked service? That way, repositories don't come into play at all (as that is not what you are testing anway)

Comment: `mvc-servlet-context.xml` has a `component-scan`, which instanciates all controllers in the system. the controllers have `@Autowire's` to various services and/or repositories. Testing `FooController` still requires you to mock `BarService` used in `BarController`

Comment: I have updated my snippets, but thinking about this more, what I want is probably not possible.

Comment: I am assuming that when you say 'by hand' you mean adding an additional method in MockServices. I don't consider that a big overhead (as long as your tests work for you). However, I would keep it very simply by simply focusing on the controller and not worrying about WebAppConfiguration, xml etc (not saying your approach is wrong). Instead of writing and updating MockServices, you could simply **@Mock YourService service** in your controller test. If setting the service is a problem, you can autowire Controller constructor that takes in your Service. Hope it helps!

Comment: What you want can be done with a different mocking tool, JMockit (which I develop). You would simply need to declare mock fields annotated as `@Capturing`, so that the implementation classes instantiated by Spring would get mocked.

Comment: JMockit looks very interesting. is there an equivilent to this piece of Mockito code `@Bean
    public FooService fooService() {
        return Mockito.mock(FooService.class);
    }`

Answer (score 0):

An MVC Controller is implemented normally like a glue code that integrates the Model with the View.  For example, when invoking an EJB from the Controller and then updating the View model.

So, a Controller test may have sence when indeed you mock all your dependencies and verify that this integration or "glue code" is working as expected. In general, if an integration test implies too many components, maybe a modularization of the whole sut may be necessary for the system to be  actually testable.

Anyway, if you find integration test laborious, maybe you can try to get the most coverage for each standalone component and let functional tests get the Controller coverage.